# Categorizing Custom Posts in Bulk Based on Title

Tags: custom-post-types, categories, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I'm working on the website of a client who used pages for every type of content in their not so small website. What they've done is created 400 pages for different projects they have interacted with. To display them on the website they've created a manual list that is broken up in categories. All projects are pasted as anchor links in the text editor under a heading for the category. So there is no real, data in admin tagging projects in their respective categories.

I've transitioned all of these projects to a custom post type, however I have to figure out how to break them up in their respective categories so that they can be filtered, sorted etc. All I have to go from is the manual list they've created so that would mean I only have titles.

I was thinking on running db queries adding cats to projects based on title, but is there a better way? Or any other alternative?

Comment: WP CLI might be more reliable and compatible than SQL queries as it fires hooks and doesn't have PHP time and memory limits. Most importantly though, try to phrase your question in a way that gets you a specific factually correct answer, if you're just asking for recommendations then that won't work here ( out of scope ) and the answers you get will be of poorer quality and fewer in number